# Frame of programatic view not set in viewDidLoad()

Tags: swift

I'm overriding `loadView()` so have the following

```
let testView = UIView()
    
override func loadView() {       
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    
        self.view.addSubview(testView)
        testView.backgroundColor = .brown
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            testView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        ])
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print (testView.frame) // (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}
```

now when I want to alter subviews before they appear, it seems the frames of the subviews are not set until viewDidAppear - but I expected them to be set in `viewDidLoad()`

What is the earliest point such a frame will be set?

Comment: `layoutSubview()`, that the early one. When `didLoad()` is called, it's called in memory, and constraints are not applied (didn't render yet). In didAppear, they might be called, but not until layoutDidSubview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View is basically rendered when `layoutSubview()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called. `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillAppear()` are called early when constraints are not applied yet and view is not rendered. You can check once `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called or `viewDidAppear()`